# Two times looping 1D with different configurations

Tags: fortran, vectorization, gfortran, intel-fortran

Does anyone know, why `Program B` faster than `Program A` is?

I used `ifort-16` with `-fast` optimization flag and the optimization reports say that `Program A` would give estimated potential speed up 10.09, while `Program B` only 3.90. But, actually the running time of `Program B` is 14s, while `Program A` is 20s.

```
!Program A
 DO J=1, 100000          !This is the different part
   !$OMP SIMD
    DO I=1, 100000
       IF(A(I)==J) THEN
          B(I)=J
       END IF          
    END DO
   !$OMP END SIMD
 END DO

!Program B
 DO I=1, 100000          !This is the different part
   !$OMP SIMD
    DO J=1, 100000
       IF(A(I)==J) THEN
          B(I)=J
       END IF          
    END DO
   !$OMP END SIMD
 END DO
```

Well, both programs were successfully vectorized and somehow my feeling says that `program A` would be faster, since (*in my opinion*), both codes would be vectorized as follows:

```
!Program A
 IF(A(I)==J) THEN
    B(I)=J
 END IF

 IF(A(I+1)==J) THEN
    B(I+1)=J
 END IF

...
```

and

```
!Program B
 IF(A(I)==J) THEN
    B(I)=J
 END IF

 IF(A(I)==J+1) THEN
    B(I)=J+1
 END IF

...
```

where `Program A` will be more effective, since the left-hand-side indexes are directly computed. But in fact, my expectations were wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The run time of a program includes many components. The one that we most of the time look at is the computation time. However, we also have the memory access that is the bottleneck of most programs. There are other components but I will limit myself to these two.
In your case, the memory access is potentially what is making the difference.

In program B, the internal loop (with `J` index) that runs `100000` access the same memory space `A(I)` and `B(I)` for each iteration of the external loop (`I` index). Once those are loaded into registers, there is no need to go to memory anymore. The program is going to the memory only when the index `I` of the outer loop changes. That is `100000` times

In program A, the internal loop (with `I` index) that runs `100000` access different memory locations `A(I)` and `B(I)` for each iteration of the internal loop. Since there is no way you can have the `100000` in the registers, the CPU will have to wait for the data. And since the outer loop (`J` index) is also run `100000` times, you have `100000x100000` memory access for program A compared to the `100000` for the program B.

That is one possible explanation of what you observed.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Actually at first I thought also like that. So the possibility of the main problem here is the memory access. I haven't tested it yet with `Gfortran`, but hopefully I will get the same results (perspectives), since sometimes `Ifort` and `Gfortran` could give the different characteristics even for some simple and fundamental problems.

Comment: Just a side thought, you should be able to eliminate one loop. The two of them seem to not be necessary.

Comment: Yes sure I don't need these 2 loopings. All codes I posted here are just some simple examples, that I want to know the characteristics of `Ifort` and `Gfortran`.

Comment: Comparing two compilers on their ability to eliminate redundant loops (and the extent to which an omp directive interferes) doesn't seem a sufficient motivation for this example.  gfortran developers have posted some comments on their thinking about omp simd implementation where it differs from ifort.